# Having Problems getting OpenModelica to run / error code 1

Tags: openmodelica

I just downloaded OpenModelica and installed the latest build in C:\OpenModelica1.14.1
Starting the connection-editor, not one of the modelica example seems to run.
An .exe-file is being created in the temp folder;
on the other hand, i could not find ModelName.log (using the Modelica example LogicalNetwork1) I always run into the same error, which is:

_______output_______

C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//share/omc/scripts/Compile.bat Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1 gcc mingw64 parallel 8 0
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM Arguments

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM 1 fileprefix

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM 2 target (gcc|msvc)

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM 3 platform (mingw64|mingw32)

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM 4 serial/parallel

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM 5 number of processors

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM 6 LOGGING 0/1

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>if not "8" == "" (set NUM_PROCS=8 )  else (set NUM_PROCS=8 )

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>if not "0" == "" (set LOGGING=0 )  else (set LOGGING=1 )

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set OM_PLATFORM=mingw64

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM Clear all environment variables that may interfere during compile and link phases.

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set GCC_EXEC_PREFIX=

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set C_INCLUDE_PATH=

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set LIBRARY_PATH=

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set OLD_PATH=C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\bin;C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\lib;C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin;C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\tools\msys\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\5.3.0;C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\tools\msys\usr\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;E:\Programme\Delphi7\Bin;E:\Programme\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>call :CONVERT_OPENMODELICAHOME_TO_SHORT_PATH_NAME "C:/OpenModelica1.14.1/"

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set OPENMODELICAHOME=C:\OPENMO~1.1\

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>EXIT /B 0

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set MINGW="C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64"

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set ADDITIONAL_ARGS=

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM If OMDEV is set, use MinGW from there instead of OPENMODELICAHOME

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM It is not certain that release OMC is installed

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>if not a == a set MINGW=\tools\msys\mingw64

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM echo OPENMODELICAHOME = C:\OPENMO~1.1\ >> Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.log 2>&1

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>REM echo MINGW = "C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64" >>Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.log 2>&1

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>call :CONVERT_CD_TO_SHORT_PATH_NAME "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1"

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>set CURRENT_DIR="C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG"

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>EXIT /B 0

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>if 0 == 1 (goto :SET_PATH_LOG )  else (goto :SET_PATH )

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1>cd /D ""C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64"\bin"

C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin>set PATH=C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin;C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin....\usr\bin;

C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin>echo PATH = "C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin;C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin....\usr\bin;" 
PATH = "C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin;C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin....\usr\bin;"

C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin>cd /D ""C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG""

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>goto :CHECK_TARGET

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>if /I "gcc" == "msvc" (goto :MSVC )

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>if /I "gcc" == "msvc10" (goto :MSVC100 )

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>if /I "gcc" == "msvc12" (goto :MSVC110 )

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>if /I "gcc" == "msvc13" (goto :MSVC120 )

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>if /I "gcc" == "msvc15" (goto :MSVC140 )  else (goto :MINGW )

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>REM echo "MINGW"

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>if "parallel" == "parallel" set ADDITIONAL_ARGS=-j8

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>if 0 == 1 (""C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64"\bin\mingw32-make" -w -f Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.makefile -j8   1>>Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.log 2>&1 )  else (""C:\OPENMO~1.1\tools\msys\mingw64"\bin\mingw32-make" -w -f Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.makefile -j8 ) 
mingw32-make: Entering directory 'C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/OPENMO~1/OMEdit/MODELI~1.LOG'
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_functions.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_functions.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_records.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_records.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_01exo.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_01exo.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_02nls.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_02nls.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_03lsy.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_03lsy.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_04set.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_04set.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_05evt.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_05evt.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_06inz.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_06inz.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_07dly.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_07dly.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_08bnd.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_08bnd.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_09alg.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_09alg.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_10asr.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_10asr.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_11mix.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_11mix.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_12jac.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_12jac.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_13opt.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_13opt.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_14lnz.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_14lnz.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_15syn.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_15syn.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_16dae.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_16dae.c
gcc  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0  -c -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_17inl.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_17inl.c
gcc -I. -o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.exe Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_functions.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_records.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_01exo.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_02nls.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_03lsy.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_04set.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_05evt.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_06inz.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_07dly.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_08bnd.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_09alg.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_10asr.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_11mix.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_12jac.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_13opt.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_14lnz.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_15syn.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_16dae.o Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1_17inl.o -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0 -L"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.3/Blocks"  "-LC:/OpenModelica1.14.1//lib//omc" "-LC:/OpenModelica1.14.1//lib/" "-L%APPDATA%/.openmodelica/binaries/Modelica" "-LC:/OpenModelica1.14.1/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.3/Resources/Library/mingw64" "-LC:/OpenModelica1.14.1/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.3/Resources/Library/win64" "-LC:/OpenModelica1.14.1/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.3/Resources/Library" -lModelicaStandardTables -lModelicaIO -lModelicaMatIO -lzlib  -Os -falign-functions -fno-ipa-pure-const -mstackrealign -msse2 -mfpmath=sse     -I"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//include/omc/c" -I. -DOPENMODELICA_XML_FROM_FILE_AT_RUNTIME -DOMC_MODEL_PREFIX=Modelica_Blocks_Examples_LogicalNetwork1 -DOMC_NUM_MIXED_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_LINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NUM_NONLINEAR_SYSTEMS=0 -DOMC_NDELAY_EXPRESSIONS=0 -DOMC_NVAR_STRING=0 -L"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//lib//omc" -L"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//lib" -Wl,--stack,16777216,-rpath,"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//lib//omc" -Wl,-rpath,"C:/OpenModelica1.14.1//lib"   -fopenmp -Wl,-Bstatic -lregex -ltre -lintl -liconv -lexpat -lomcgc -lpthread -loleaut32 -limagehlp -lhdf5 -lz -lszip -Wl,-Bdynamic  -Wl,-Bstatic -lSimulationRuntimeC -Wl,-Bdynamic -Wl,-Bstatic -lomcgc -lregex -ltre -lintl -liconv -lexpat -static-libgcc -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32 -limagehlp -lws2_32 -llis -lumfpack -lklu -lcolamd -lbtf -lamd  -lsundials_idas -lsundials_kinsol -lsundials_nvecserial -lipopt -lcoinmumps -lpthread -lm -lgfortranbegin -lgfortran -lquadmath -lmingw32 -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -luser32 -lkernel32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lopenblas -lcminpack -Wl,-Bdynamic -lwsock32 -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic 
mingw32-make: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Temp/OPENMO~1/OMEdit/MODELI~1.LOG'

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>set RESULT=0

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>if 0 == 1 echo RESULT: 0  1>>Modelica.Blocks.Examples.LogicalNetwork1.log 2>&1

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>goto :Final

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>set PATH=C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\bin;C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\lib;C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\tools\msys\mingw64\bin;C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\tools\msys\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\5.3.0;C:\OpenModelica1.14.1\tools\msys\usr\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;E:\Programme\Delphi7\Bin;E:\Programme\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\Mercurial;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>set OLD_PATH= 
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>EXIT /B 0 
Compilation process failed. Exited with code 1.

---

compile.bat :

```
    @echo off
    REM Arguments
    REM 1 fileprefix
    REM 2 target (gcc|msvc)
    REM 3 platform (mingw64|mingw32)
    REM 4 serial/parallel
    REM 5 number of processors
    REM 6 LOGGING 0/1
    if not "%5"=="" (set NUM_PROCS=%5) else (set NUM_PROCS=%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%)
    if not "%6"=="" (set LOGGING=%6) else (set LOGGING=1)
    set OM_PLATFORM=%3
    REM Clear all environment variables that may interfere during compile and link phases.
    set GCC_EXEC_PREFIX=
    set CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=
    set C_INCLUDE_PATH=
    set LIBRARY_PATH=
    set OLD_PATH=%PATH%
    call :CONVERT_OPENMODELICAHOME_TO_SHORT_PATH_NAME "%OPENMODELICAHOME%"
    set MINGW="%OPENMODELICAHOME%\tools\msys\%OM_PLATFORM%"
    set ADDITIONAL_ARGS=
    REM If OMDEV is set, use MinGW from there instead of OPENMODELICAHOME
    REM It is not certain that release OMC is installed
    if not %OMDEV%a==a set MINGW=%OMDEV%\tools\msys\%OM_PLATFORM%
    REM echo OPENMODELICAHOME = %OPENMODELICAHOME% >> %1.log 2>&1
    REM echo MINGW = %MINGW% >>%1.log 2>&1
    call :CONVERT_CD_TO_SHORT_PATH_NAME "%CD%"

    if %LOGGING%==1 (goto :SET_PATH_LOG) else (goto :SET_PATH)

    :SET_PATH_LOG
    cd /D "%MINGW%\bin" >>%CURRENT_DIR%\%1.log 2>&1
    set PATH=%CD%;%CD%\..\..\usr\bin; >>%CURRENT_DIR%\%1.log 2>&1
    cd /D "%CURRENT_DIR%" >>%CURRENT_DIR%\%1.log 2>&1
    goto :CHECK_TARGET

    :SET_PATH
    cd /D "%MINGW%\bin"
    set PATH=%CD%;%CD%\..\..\usr\bin;
    echo PATH = "%PATH%"
    cd /D "%CURRENT_DIR%"
    goto :CHECK_TARGET

    REM echo PATH = %PATH% >>%1.log 2>&1
    REM echo CD = %CD% >>%1.log 2>&1

    :CHECK_TARGET
    if /I "%2"=="msvc" (goto :MSVC)
    if /I "%2"=="msvc10" (goto :MSVC100)
    if /I "%2"=="msvc12" (goto :MSVC110)
    if /I "%2"=="msvc13" (goto :MSVC120)
    if /I "%2"=="msvc15" (goto :MSVC140) else (goto :MINGW)

    :MSVC
    REM echo "MSVC"
    REM check if msvc is there
    if defined VS140COMNTOOLS (goto :MSVC140)
    if defined VS120COMNTOOLS (goto :MSVC120)
    if defined VS110COMNTOOLS (goto :MSVC110)
    if not defined VS100COMNTOOLS (goto :MINGW)
    goto :MSVC100

    :MSVC100
    REM "Use Visual Studio 2010"
    set MSVCHOME=%VS100COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC
    if not exist "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat" (goto :MINGW)
    set PATHTMP=%PATH%
    set PATH=%OLD_PATH%
    if %LOGGING%==1 (call "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat" >> %1.log 2>&1) else (call "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat")
    goto :MSVCCOMPILE

    :MSVC110
    REM "Use Visual Studio 2012"
    set MSVCHOME=%VS110COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC
    if not exist "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat" (goto :MINGW)
    set PATHTMP=%PATH%
    set PATH=%OLD_PATH%
    if %LOGGING%==1 (call "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat" >> %1.log 2>&1) else (call "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat")
    goto :MSVCCOMPILE

    :MSVC120
    REM "Use Visual Studio 2013"
    echo "msvc120"
    set MSVCHOME=%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC
    if not exist "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat" (goto :MINGW)
    set PATHTMP=%PATH%
    set PATH=%OLD_PATH%
    if %LOGGING%==1 (call "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat" >> %1.log 2>&1) else (call "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat")
    goto :MSVCCOMPILE

    :MSVC140
    REM "Use Visual Studio 2015"
    set MSVCHOME=%VS140COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC
    if not exist "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat" (goto :MINGW)
    set PATHTMP=%PATH%
    set PATH=%OLD_PATH%
    if %LOGGING%==1 (call "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat" >> %1.log 2>&1) else (call "%MSVCHOME%\vcvarsall.bat")
    goto :MSVCCOMPILE

    :MSVCCOMPILE
    set MAKE=
    set MAKEFLAGS=
    if %LOGGING%==1 (nmake /a /f %1.makefile >> %1.log 2>&1) else (nmake /a /f %1.makefile)
    set RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
    if %LOGGING%==1 echo RESULT: %RESULT% >> %1.log 2>&1
    goto :Final

    :MINGW
    REM echo "MINGW"
    if "%4"=="parallel" set ADDITIONAL_ARGS=-j%NUM_PROCS%
    if %LOGGING%==1 ("%MinGW%\bin\mingw32-make" -w -f %1.makefile %ADDITIONAL_ARGS%  >> %1.log 2>&1) else ("%MinGW%\bin\mingw32-make" -w -f %1.makefile %ADDITIONAL_ARGS%)
    set RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
    if %LOGGING%==1 echo RESULT: %RESULT% >> %1.log 2>&1
    goto :Final

    :Final
    set PATH=%OLD_PATH%
    set OLD_PATH=
    @%COMSPEC% /C exit %RESULT%
    EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

    :CONVERT_CD_TO_SHORT_PATH_NAME
    set CURRENT_DIR="%~s1"
    EXIT /B 0

    :CONVERT_OPENMODELICAHOME_TO_SHORT_PATH_NAME
    set OPENMODELICAHOME=%~s1
    EXIT /B 0
```

[i typed this into the command window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYenV.png)

Comment: Is Modelica.Blocks.Examples.BooleanNetwork1.exe created in the %TEMP%/OpenModelica/OMEdit/Modelica.Blocks.Examples.BooleanNetwork1/ folder?

Comment: yes, it is being created in this folder each time
by the way, i´m running a x64 windows 10 setup

Comment: Ok, it seems the simulation executable is generated but then somehow cannot run to produce the simulation results. What kind of antivirus do you have?

Comment: Can you copy %OPENMODELICAHOME%\share\omc\scripts\Compile.bat someplace (to be able to put it back) and then edit the file and remove: "@echo off" so that we get more output when we compile? Then compile BooleanNetwork1 again and update the output here.

Comment: just did so, the output is in the edited question. i use avast antivirus. i tried simulating while the antivirus is turned off, but ran into the same error (not sure if the windows defender sprang into action instead, but didnt look like it). using but one kernel or running different integration methods also gave the same error.

Comment: Seems the problem is with line "@%COMSPEC% /C exit %RESULT%" in the Compile.bat script. Maybe you don't have %COMSPEC% defined?! Anyhow, write REM in front of that line like: REM @%COMSPEC% /C exit %RESULT% and try to compile again.

Comment: well at least that removes the "system cant find path"-line. still, the last lines read: C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>set OLD_PATH= 

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>REM @C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C exit 0 

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Temp\OPENMO~1\OMEdit\MODELI~1.LOG>EXIT /B 0 
Compilation process failed. Exited with code 1.

the comspec environment was set to the path you mentioned, too

Comment: This is just weird. Let's try to edit that line again, to: %COMSPEC% /C exit %RESULT%. I mean without REM @.

Comment: editing the line to not include the @-sign in front of %COMSPEC% still does not seem to do the trick...
my roommate runs a linux distribution on his laptop, if he has any luck getting OM to run i think i´ll just try setting up a virtual machine or a dual-boot to run OM, python etc. on linux. i did, however, put the compile.bat file (which is back to its original) in the question, not sure if that´s any help.

Comment: I just don't get why it doesn't work. Is like it doesn't find cmd.exe via COMSPEC. Unfortunately I'm out of ideas here. Is cmd.exe present at that path? The simulation executable is build fine but the Compile.bat script fails somehow. On Linux everything should work fine. We have a virtual machine image with the latest OM if you need one.

Comment: If you start a Start->cmd.exe and then write "%COMSPEC% /C exit 0" without the quotes in it, does it gives any error?

Comment: wasnt sure what to expect, but in this case also, the path couldnt be found (i added a screenshot of the cmd in the question).
would be glad to try using your VM image for the time being! at least until i can get to setting up a dual boot system

Comment: The VM is here: https://openmodelica.org/download/virtual-machine.

Comment: Seems your %COMPSPEC% variable exists but it points to a place where cmd.exe does not exists?! In a Start->cmd.exe do: dir /a %COMPSPEC% and see what that gives you. You can also search your computer to find out where cmd.exe is present.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed several issues that could go wrong when compiling models after the installation. Let's see if we can narrow this down.

1. somehow the environment variables are not set correctly, try a restart
2. antivirus or user/group policy doesn't let you run GCC or to create executables in the temp directory; check if %TEMP%/OpenModelica/OMEdit/ModelName/ you have ModelName.exe, if not, have a look for ModelName.log and see what's inside

To get more info during model compilation edit (after you save it someplace so you can replace it back later on):

```
%OPENMODELICAHOME%\share\omc\scripts\Compile.bat
```

And remove `@echo off` or change it to `REM @echo off` so that we ge more info when compiling a model. Then compile a model again.

Make sure %COMSPEC% environment variable is defined, mine is set to:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

[image]

Also, make sure that cmd.exe actually exists?!

[image]

Comment: Thanks Adrian!
i just edited my original post and looked into the suggestions you made; also i pasted the whole text the compole window showed